# Sprite Kit - Draw circle with muilticolored borders

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to draw a circle similar to this:

[image: image desc]

I'm going to have different objects interact (collide) with the circle but the objects will interact differently depending on which color is touched.

Can this be done using bezier paths? I will want each color of the circle set as a different variable.

My original idea was to draw the circle in photoshop and import it into Sprite Kit but I don't know how to separate the colors into different variables this way.

Comment: What is with the inner area of the ring ? Is it possible to happen that any node ends up spawned in there ? Also, note that when writing a question, it is always good practice to show what you've have tried so far to solve the issue. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the object into your game as a png (from photoshop or whatever) and when a node collides with it, detect the point it contacts and calculate the difference in x and y from the center of the circle.  Even if the circle is rotating, this should always tell you what color the colliding object hit, as long as you have the colors mapped to "zones" already.  make sense?

Alternatively, you could create a transparent circle (SKShapeNode) and have eight SKShapeNode arcs as children of that transparent circle.  Position them deliberately.  This adds the benefit that each will be a separate object, can have its own strokeColor, and its own touch methods. They would need to be collision-able while the parent transparent circle would need to ignore collisions for it to work.

As for how to detect which section of the circle was hit, here is how I would do it:

Given a circle that is divided into 8 equally sized pie pieces, you should be able to determine which section received a collision based on the x and y values of the collision point compared to the center of the circle.  For example, assuming that the Y axis is a division between two halves of four sections each (see pic), you can first narrow the collision down by quadrant as follows:

[image: Circle with 8 sections]

cx, cy = collision x and y values
ox, oy = the x and y values of the very center (origin) of the circle

pseudocode:

```
if cx > ox && cy > oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 1
if cx > ox && cy < oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 2
if cx < ox && cy < oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 3
if cx < ox && cy > oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 4
```

Since there are two sections in each quadrant you can further refine this logic, determining which section of the two the collision occurred in by comparing the difference

pseudocode:

```
if the difference between cx and ox > the difference between cy and oy, then the collision occurred in Section 2
else the collision occurred in section 1
```

Combining these logics into one nested if-else statement you'd have something like this:

pseudocode:

```
if cx > ox && cy > oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 1
......if the difference between cx and ox > the difference between cy and oy, then the collision occurred in Section 2
......else the collision occurred in section 1
if cx > ox && cy < oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 2
......if the difference between cx and ox > the difference between cy and oy, then the collision occurred in Section 3
......else the collision occurred in section 4
if cx < ox && cy < oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 3
......if the difference between cx and ox > the difference between cy and oy, then the collision occurred in Section 6
......else the collision occurred in section 5
if cx < ox && cy > oy, then the collision occurred in quadrant 4
......if the difference between cx and ox > the difference between cy and oy, then the collision occurred in Section 7
......else the collision occurred in section 8
```

HTH!

Comment: Both ways totally make sense. Still, there is a downside with second (SKShapeNode) approach. Each SKShapeNode will require one draw pass. Maybe a bit more coding, but the first approach would be better. Also, you don't have to make images by yourself. You can use multiple SKShapeNodes to create everything programatically (and dynamically), and then insert those in SKEffectNode and rasterize it (this will reduce number of draw calls to 1). Anyways, you have my upvote for ideas :)

Comment: Awesome.  I like your SKEffectNode rasterization idea, too.  I think I'll try that one out when I get a chance.

Comment: I know how to detect collisions but how would I map zones to different colors? Can you give me an example of what the code would look like.

Comment: I'll think about this and post something later.  I am thinking it would be an array of X, Y values that you would use to look up where the collision occurred.